# Why can't I call QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&threadObj, &QThread::start, Qt::QueuedConnection)?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a console application with a `QCoreApplication` running the event loop in `main()`.
Here i have an Object, that is a derivative of QThread, with `run()` implemented to do some testing.
I want the thread to start upon starting my application, so I called

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&threadObj, &QThread::start, Qt::QueuedConnection);
return qapp.exec();
```

at the end of `main()`.

Here is my Question: Why does this not compile?

Doing the same with `QThread::quit` works fine, yet `QThread::exit` does not.
I presume it has something to do with the arguments for `start` and `exit`?`

The Compiler Error looks like this btw:

```
d:\dev\project\project\main.cpp(49): error C2665: 'QMetaObject::invokeMethod': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>x:\hmi_qt5\qt\msvc2017_x86\debug\include\qtcore\qobjectdefs.h(448): note: could be 'bool QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject *,const char *,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument)' (compiling source file main.cpp)
1>x:\hmi_qt5\qt\msvc2017_x86\debug\include\qtcore\qobjectdefs.h(431): note: or       'bool QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument)' (compiling source file main.cpp)
1>x:\hmi_qt5\qt\msvc2017_x86\debug\include\qtcore\qobjectdefs.h(414): note: or       'bool QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject *,const char *,QGenericReturnArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument,QGenericArgument)' (compiling source file main.cpp)
1>d:\dev\project\project\main.cpp(49): note: while trying to match the argument list '(threadObj*, void (__thiscall QThread::* )(QThread::Priority), Qt::ConnectionType)'
```

Thanks in Advance,

Bob

PS:
I do have a workaround for this, either by using functors or implementing a custom slot in `threadObj`.
I asked this because I'm curious as to why this doesn't work, since I think the syntax is fine.

Comment: Qt Version? C++ Std Version?

Comment: @Superlokkus I use Qt 5.12 and C++11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the existence of a parameter of `QThread::start`, although defaulted, and Qt is broken in the aspect that the most important overloads of `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` are defined with `const char *member` as the 2nd parameter. So using one of those overloads you can use it directly:

```
#include <functional>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

#include <QThread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QThread threadObj;
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&threadObj, "start", Qt::QueuedConnection);

    QApplication this_application(argc, argv);
    return this_application.exec();
}
```

Another solution would be

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&threadObj, std::bind(&QThread::start,std::ref(threadObj),QThread::InheritPriority), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

which is almost the same as a lambda, but IMHO clearer intention.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems I have found the answer.
The  problem does not lie within Qt, as i originally expected, but within C++.
When using function pointers for indirect function calls, only functions with an empty argument list can be called. (Like `QThread::quit(void)`)
When calling a function that has a parameter list, including a default parameter, it implicitly calls the function with the explicit parameter. This does not work here, since there can not be arguments in a functoin pointer.

The correct way to implement this seems to be a lambda.

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&threadObj, [&threadObj]() {threadObj.start(); }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

This way, you can still check the validity of the statement at compile time.

Greetings, Bob

Comment: Its not a problem of C++ but the missing overloads of the invokeMethod Function. since C++11 they could have dropped the whole Signal/Slot thing altogether.

Comment: wouldn't dropping signals and slots make it a lot harder to communicate between objects?

Comment: Not really, except that it would not hide the convoluted mess Qt is anymore. I strongly recommend to any beginner, to use Qt only for the GUI logic. If you have long running functions which need callbacks, use `std::function`, `std::future` or templated parameters, but do not include one single Qt header in your problem solving code.

I have done this even with completely different threading models, but with the advantage of not depending on Qt except for the GUI: https://github.com/Superlokkus/s70357-it2-beleg  So I moved to use Javascript for the GUI in my new projects